# ¿Cómo puedo sacar una imagen guardada en byte en sql mangament a un datagrid en c#?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

Necesito que en el datagrid me salga todo el texto(que ya me sale), es decir producto,descripcion... pero tambien la imagen, pero no consigo pasarlo a byte y que salga bien.

```
        var select = "SELECT nombrePro as Producto, descPro as Descripción, categoriaPro as Categoria, precioPro as Precio, stockPro as Stock, image as Imagen FROM Productos WHERE categoriaPro='Multimedia' AND stockPro>0";
        Helper helperclass = new Helper();
        var c = new SqlConnection(helperclass.getConnectionDB(@"(localdb)\BrunsdDB1", "BrunsdDB1")); // Your Connection String here

        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);


        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);


        var ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir un [BitMapImage](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=net-5.0) para recuperar ese campo, en sqlServer los campos image se guardan como array de bytes, entonces tienes que convertirlo a un formato legible.

```
public static BitmapImage RecogerImagen(byte[] bytesImagen)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytesImagen);
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: Y como paso por el método a solo lo que es la imagen, es decir en mi código como puedo diferenciar lo que es "image" y pasarlo por el método. Gracias por responderme!

Comment: Tienes que recorrer tu `dataAdapter`, con un foreach o similar y castear el elemento a byte[]   `imagen = (byte[])TuCampoImagen;`